# Understanding Koch curve algorithm

Tags: python, python-turtle

More specifically I don't understand how it draws that line each time to create a line even if the only condition that is logic to draw a line is when `n == 0`.

```
import turtle as t

def kochedessin(n,cote):
    if(n == 0):
        t.fd(cote)
    else:
        kochedessin(n-1, cote/3)
        t.left(60)
        kochedessin(n-1, cote/3)
        t.left(-120)
        kochedessin(n-1, cote/3)
        t.left(60)
        kochedessin(n-1, cote/3)

kochedessin(3, 100)
```

Comment: The function is recursive. So it keeps calling itself with a smaller `n`, and when it reaches `0` it draws the line. In between all these recursive calls it changes direction.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that the function `kochedessin` is called recursively, and with each recursive call, the value of `n` is decremented by 1. This eventually leads to the base case when `n == 0`, at which point the turtle actually moves forward and draws a line.

Let's consider the case when `kochedessin(3, 100)` is called initially.

In the first call, `n` is not 0, so the function proceeds to the recursive calls:

1. `kochedessin(n-1, cote/3)` - This call has `n=2` and `cote=100/3`. The turtle does not draw a line yet, but the function will call itself recursively again.
2. `t.left(60)` - The turtle turns left by 60 degrees.
3. `kochedessin(n-1, cote/3)` - This call has `n=2` and `cote=100/3`. The turtle does not draw a line yet, but the function will call itself recursively again.
4. `t.left(-120)` - The turtle turns right by 120 degrees.
5. `kochedessin(n-1, cote/3)` - This call has `n=2` and `cote=100/3`. The turtle does not draw a line yet, but the function will call itself recursively again.
6. `t.left(60)` - The turtle turns left by 60 degrees.
7. `kochedessin(n-1, cote/3)` - This call has `n=2` and `cote=100/3`. The turtle does not draw a line yet, but the function will call itself recursively again.

The function will continue to call itself recursively until the value of `n` reaches 0. At that point, the turtle will draw a line with the length `cote/3^depth`, where `depth` is the depth of the recursion (in this case, `depth = 3`).

The sequence of left turns, right turns, and recursive calls to `kochedessin` with decreasing values of `n` ultimately shapes the Koch curve. When the base case `n == 0` is reached at every level of recursion, the turtle will draw a series of smaller line segments that together form the Koch curve.

To visualize how the curve is built, you can think of it as a set of four smaller Koch curves connected by the turtle's turns:

1. Draw a Koch curve with `n-1` depth and `cote/3` length.
2. Turn left 60 degrees.
3. Draw a Koch curve with `n-1` depth and `cote/3` length.
4. Turn right 120 degrees.
5. Draw a Koch curve with `n-1` depth and `cote/3` length.
6. Turn left 60 degrees.
7. Draw a Koch curve with `n-1` depth and `cote/3` length.

When the depth of recursion reaches 0, the turtle will draw lines instead of making recursive calls, ultimately forming the complete Koch curve.